при получении списка файлов не отображаются файлы из папок
Делаю плеер на ардуино и столкнулся с проблемой, при получении списка файлов не отображаются файлы из папок, вот код:
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <TMRpcm.h>
#include <LCD_1602_RUS.h>
#include <GyverEncoder.h>

Encoder enc(2, 3, 5);
LCD_1602_RUS lcd(0x27, 20, 4);
TMRpcm audio;

#define maxFiles 50
char *songList[maxFiles];
int count = 0;
File root;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor((20 - 8) / 2, 1);
  lcd.print("AirAudio");
  if (!SD.begin(4)){
    lcd.setCursor((20 - 8) / 2, 2);
    lcd.print("SD error");
    while(true);
  }
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.home();
  lcd.print("Загрузка...");
  
  root = SD.open("/");

  printDirectory(root, 0);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
  while (true) {

    File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
    if (! entry) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
      Serial.print('\t');
    }
    Serial.print(entry.name());
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.println("/");
      printDirectory(entry, numTabs + 1);
    } else {
      // files have sizes, directories do not
      songList[count] = entry.name();
      count++;
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
    }
    entry.close();
  }
}

Вот вывод:
SYSTEM~1/
MUSIC.WAV       2911596
MDIR/


А что в реальности лежит на карте?
